# uploading image and Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, html

How to solve that also in IE like?:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //i want to hide the <input type="file"...>
```

and file explorer opening width am image clicking

```
    $("#preview").html('<img src="uploads/default.png" class="preview" />').click(function() {
        $('#imgfile').click();
    });
```

there is ok in firefox, ghrome, safari and opera

```
    $('#imgfile').bind('change', function() {
        $("#preview").html('');
        $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
```

...but in internet explorer the ajaxForm-function doesnt work and stay to show a loading image:

```
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#preview'
        }).submit();
    });
    $("#imgfile").hide();
});
```

And html-code is there:

```
<div style="width:600px">
    <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
        <input type="file" name="imgfile" id="imgfile" />
    </form>
    <div id='preview'></div>
</div>
```

and css-code:

```
.preview {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:solid 1px #dedede;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    color:#cc0000;
    font-size:12px
}
```

..and ajaimage.php looks like:

```
<?php
$path = "uploads/";
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $name = $_FILES['imgfile']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['imgfile']['size'];
    if(strlen($name)) {
        list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
        if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
            if($size<(1024*1024)) {
                $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                $tmp = $_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'];
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                    echo '<img src="uploads/'.$actual_image_name.'" class="preview" />';
                else echo "failed";
            } else echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
        } else echo "Invalid file format..";    
    } else echo "Please select image..!";
}
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're asking. Are you asking how to show the loading image while uploading, or how to use an image as the file button, or something else?

Comment: I want to use image as a button.

Comment: not clear what problem is.

Comment: Try http://demos.9lessons.info/ajaximageupload/imageajax.php width Ghrome, and then try it width Internet Explorer.